# Adding an actionlistener to a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

```
public class BelishaBeacon { 

public class Design extends JPanel { 

    private boolean alternateColors = false; 

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; 
        //creating the shapes 
        Rectangle box1 = new Rectangle(163, 180, 16, 45); 
        Rectangle box2 = new Rectangle(163, 225, 16, 45); 
        Rectangle box3 = new Rectangle(163, 270, 16, 45); 
        Rectangle box4 = new Rectangle(163, 315, 16, 45); 
        Rectangle box5 = new Rectangle(163, 360, 16, 45); 
        Rectangle box6 = new Rectangle(163, 405, 16, 45); 
        //drawing the shapes 
        Ellipse2D.Double ball = new Ellipse2D.Double(a, b, 100, 100); 
        g2.draw(ball); 
        g2.draw(box1); 
        g2.draw(box2); 
        g2.draw(box3); 
        g2.draw(box4); 
        g2.draw(box5); 
        g2.draw(box6); 
        //coloring the shapes 
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
        g2.fill(box1); 
        g2.fill(box3); 
        g2.fill(box5); 
        g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW); 
        g2.fill(ball); 

        if (alternateColors) { 
            g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE); 
            g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(a, b, 100, 100)); 
        } 

        alternateColors = false; 
    } 

    public void alternateColors() { 
        alternateColors = true; 
        repaint(); 
    } 
} 


public BelishaBeacon() { 
    //frame 
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 
    frame.setSize(330, 550); 
    frame.setTitle("Belisha Beacon"); 
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0)); 
    final Design shapes = new Design(); 

    JButton jbtFlash = new JButton("Flash"); 
 jbtFlash.addActionListener( 
          new ActionListener() { 
               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                  Runnable r = new Runnable(){
                          @Override
                           public void run(){
                          while(/* user stops / toggleButton state*/ true)
                                {
                          swapColors(); // some method using static boolean
                                   try{
                                        Thread.sleep(500);
                                     }catch(Exception e){}
                                }

                           }

                        private void swapColors() {
                              boolean swapColors;
                            Graphics g2;
                            if (swapColors) { 
                               g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE); 
                             g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(a, b, 100, 100)); 
                                } else {
                                    g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW); 
                             g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(a, b, 100, 100)); 
                                }

                        }



                }; 
                Thread t = new Thread(r);
                t.start();
                }});
    JButton jbtSteady = new JButton("Steady"); 
    jbtSteady.addActionListener( 
            new ActionListener() { 
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                    shapes.alternateColors(); 
                } 
            });
```

I have created an action listener for my jbutton steady and flash, I am just trying to created a method for swapColors for it to be initialised in the jbutton flash. The swapcolos method initially should alternate between the colours orange and grey

Comment: So you need to alternate colors of shapes by clicking JButton jbtFlash?

Comment: I think you need to create a class that implements `ActionListener` and then use this new class in the `addActionListener` method

Comment: yeah basically I've done it for the jbutton called steady which changes colour from yellow to orange, but i'm not too sure how to make the same jbutton for flash which flashes every half a second from orange to grey

Comment: you can consider parametrizing `alternateColors(Color colorOne, ColorColorTwo)`

Comment: tried `jbtFlash.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){......... ` ?

Comment: Consider using a JToggledButton...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote that you want it to flash every 0.5 seconds.

To do so you need to start new thread for example

```
jbtFlash.addActionListener( 
        new ActionListener() { 
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                Runnable r = new Runnable(){
                       @Override
                       public void run(){
                            while(/* user stops / toggleButton state*/ true)
                            {
                                 swapColors(); // some method using static boolean
                                 try{
                                    Thread.sleep(500);
                                 }catch(Exception e){}
                            }

                       }



            }; 
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.start();
            }});
```

Comment: when I add this to the flash jbutton it shows a red line under the whole block of code and says misplaced construct

Comment: @mdbuzz there was a problem with brackets and semicolon, try copying now, my netbeans show no errors

Comment: yeah it got rid of the red lines, however you know your method swapcolours am I supposed to create it because I dont have a method thats called swapcolours only alternatecolours

Comment: Yes, you have to write your swap colors, on your own, but its quite simple and you have it in other answers.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, I tried creating a method for swapColors but it doesn't seem to work, i'm not sure if i'm doing something wrong

Comment: You need to tell me something more, what errors, etc. Post a new question or update this one with your code sample

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75396/discussion-between-kuba-and-mdbuzz).

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (alternateColors) { 
        g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE); 
        g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(a, b, 100, 100)); 
    } 

    alternateColors = false;
```

Should be:

```
    if (alternateColors) { 
        g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE); 
        g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(a, b, 100, 100)); 
    } else {
        g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW); 
        g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(a, b, 100, 100)); 
    }
```

AND

```
public void alternateColors() { 
    alternateColors = true; 
    repaint(); 
}
```

Should be:

```
public void alternateColors() { 

    //Flip boolean alternateColors
    alternateColors = !alternateColors;

    repaint(); 
}
```

Comment: I tried this way but it just allows me to switch from orange to yellow every time I press steady, it doesn't alternate between colours when I click flash